# CakePHP 3 - Count many-to-many Association

Tags: cakephp, count, many-to-many, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I have a database with Rounds and Users. Rounds belongsToMany Users and Users belongsToMany Rounds, so a many-to-many relation. A join table rounds_users was added to do this.
EDIT: *Used the incorrect phrase here. I meant 'belongsToMany' instead of 'hasMany'*

Now I want to retrieve a list of Rounds, together with the number of linked Users per round.

*In case of a one-to-many relation something like the following would work:*

```
$rounds = $this->Rounds->find()
       ->contain(['Users' => function ($q) 
        {
            return $q->select(['Users.id', 'number' => 'COUNT(Users.round_id)'])
                    ->group(['Users.round_id']);
        }
        ]);
```

...According to [Count in contain Cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877486)

However, in a many-to-many relation `Users.round_id` does not exist. So, what could work instead?

*Note: Several questions like this have been asked already, but few about CakePHP 3.x, so I still wanted to give this a try.*

*Note 2: I can get around this by using the PHP function `count`, though I'd rather do it more elegantly*

EDIT: As suggested below, manually joining seems to do the trick:

```
$rounds_new = $this->Rounds->find()
        ->select($this->Rounds)
        ->select(['user_count' => 'COUNT(Rounds.id)'])
        ->leftJoinWith('Users')
        ->group('Rounds.id');
```

...With one problem! Rounds without Users still get a `user_count` equal to 1. What could be the problem?

Comment: You can always join in associations instead of containing them (kinda like in your **[SUM() on ManyToMany question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935419/cakephp-3-x-sum-on-manytomany)**)... besides that, if you've explicitly created `hasMany` associations (instead of `belongsToMany`), then you have a `one Rounds to many RoundsUsers` relation, ie you could still use the "count in contain" example via `RoundsUsers`, don't you?

Comment: @ndm  Whoops, I used the wrong phrase. It really is many-to-many. Manually joining seems the way to go, I added an example. This does result into a new problem.

Comment: Try using innerJoinWith instead of leftJoinWith !

Comment: @ManoharKhadka `COUNT` usually doesn't count `NULL` values, ie it should work with a `LEFT` join, and that may actually be what the OP wants, ie retrieve all rounds, and a count of `0` for rounds without users. If those `0` user rounds are unwanted, then I'd recommend an `INNER` join too.

Comment: That being said, wouldn't you want to count on `Users`?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka, @ndm, using `INNER` instead would indeed just leave out all the rows without users, which is not desired. I do want what you describe. @ndm I am not sure what you mean. I want to count Users, so I count the duplicates of otherwise unique Rounds, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Join in the association

As already mentioned in the comments, you can always join in associations instead of containing them (kinda like in your [**SUM() on ManyToMany question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935419/cakephp-3-x-sum-on-manytomany)).

The reason why you retrieve a count of `1` for rounds that do not have any associated users, is that you are counting on the wrong table. Counting on `Rounds` will of course result in a count of at least `1`, as there will always be at least `1` round, the round for which no associated users exist.

So long story short, count on `Users` instead:

```
$rounds = $this->Rounds
    ->find()
    ->select($this->Rounds)
    ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return [
            'user_count' => $query->func()->count('Users.id')
        ];
    })
    ->leftJoinWith('Users')
    ->group('Rounds.id');
```

### Counter cache for `belongsToMany` associations

There's also the counter cache behavior, it works for `belongsToMany` associations too, as long as they are set up to use a concrete join table class, which can be configured via the association configurations `through` option:

```
class RoundsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'through' => 'RoundsUsers'
        ]);
    }
}

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Rounds', [
            'through' => 'RoundsUsers'
        ]);
    }
}
```

The counter cache would be set up in the join table class, in this example `RoundsUsersTable`, which would have two `belongsTo` associations, one to `Rounds` and one to `Users`:

```
class RoundsUsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Rounds');
        $this->belongsTo('Users');

        $this->addBehavior('CounterCache', [
            'Rounds' => ['user_count']
        ]);
    }
}
```

### Count in containment

If you would have actually explicitly created `hasMany` associations (instead of belongsToMany), then you would have a `one Rounds to many RoundsUsers` relation, ie you could still use the linked "**[count in contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877486)**" example via `RoundsUsers`.

However, that would leave you with a structure where the count would be placed in a nested entity, which in turn would be missing for rounds that do not have any associated users. I would imagine that in most situations this kind of structure would require reformatting, so it's probably not the best solution. However, for the sake of completion, here's an example:

```
$rounds = $this->Rounds
    ->find()
    ->contain(['RoundsUsers' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return $query
            ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                return [
                    'RoundsUsers.round_id',
                    'number' => $query->func()->count('RoundsUsers.round_id')
                ];
            })
            ->group(['RoundsUsers.round_id']);
        }]
    );
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Returning the Total Count of Records](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > CounterCache](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > BelongsToMany Associations > Using the ‘through’ Option](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option)**