# CakePHP 3 - Contain only second-level association

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am working on a subscription system. `Users` subscribe to `Activities`, but `Activities` have `Options` (different pricing options). So `Users` are actually linked to `Options`, with `Subscriptions` acting as join table.

`Activities` `hasMany` `Options` and `Options` `hasMany` `Subscriptions`

Now I often want a list of `Subscriptions` for a specific activity, regardless of options. I found that

```
$activity = $this->Activities->get($id, ['contain' => 'Options.Subscriptions']);
```

...works well to get the options which in turn contain the subscriptions. How could go about omitting the `Options` from the contain, such that only the `Subscriptions` are found?

[image: 2nd leven contain]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to ditch the idea of using containments for that task, that's not how they work, containments will always include *additional* data.

If you want to retrieve a models records depending on other records that may be associated with them, then you should query the target model, ie `Subscriptions`, and look into using the query builders association filtering methods, namely `matching()` and `innerJoinWith()`.

It should be as simple as:

```
$query = $this->Activities->Options->Subscriptions
    ->find()
    ->matching('Options.Activities', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($id) {
        return $query->where([
            'Activities.id' => $id
        ]);
    });
```

This will create a query with the required `INNER` joins for the associations, so that it selects only subscriptions that are associated to an option that is associated to the activity with the given id.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**
- **[How to filter by conditions for associated models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models/26800203)**

Comment: Ah, `matching` is the keyword I was looking for apparently. Would you be willing to expand your answer on how to get a list of Articles with a count of their Subscriptions?

Comment: Nvm, found it. I added it to your answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Roberto That's a different task, ie it's out of the scope of your original question, so I don't think it belongs in this answer. Questions and answers for this specific task already exist, for example **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254790/cakephp-3-count-many-to-many-association**.